# Renew Letsencrypt certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to renew my letsencrypt certificate by the next command:

```
./letsencrype-auto renew
```

but I receive this error message:

```
configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.conf produced an unexpected error: Namespace object has no attribute 'standalone_supported_challenges'.
```

I if try to use the command which I created my certificate :

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone-supported-challenges tls-sni-01 -d domain
```

I get this error:

```
unrecognized arguments:  --standalone-supported-challenges tls-sni-01
```

If I try this:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d domain
```

It says:

```
The requested standalone plugin does not appear to be installed.
```

I don´t Know how to renew my certificate now.

Comment: Are you running this for Apache?

Comment: Yes. Apache 2.2

Answer (score 1):

`./letsencrype-auto renew` this should already work and should renew *all* certificates.

Try this to renew a single domain.

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d example.com
```

Comment: I prefer do not execute these command because it could change my apache configuration. For me is important execute only `standalone` plugin to renew certificates  and do not change any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

according to their documentation the auto renew feature was introduced in version 0.4.0 and does not use the syntax you have above. please refer to:

https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

> As of version 0.4.0, the letsencrypt python client supports a
>   high-level renew subcommand that attempts to renew all of your certs
>   using the same settings that you originally used to obtain them. You
>   can test it out by running:
>
> letsencrypt renew --dry-run
>
> which will obtain test certs, and shouldn’t leave any persistent
>   changes on your system. If you like the results, you can run:
>
> letsencrypt renew
>
> If you want to renew specific certificates (rather than all of them)
>   or tweak the exact parameters used for renewal, you can use the
>   letsencrypt certonly command to perform renewal of a single
>   certificate with more specific control of settings. When using
>   letsencrypt certonly, you can obtain renewal of a single certificate
>   at a time. Specify -d flags for each and every domain covered by the
>   domain that you wish to renew.

Comment: I can not use `letsencrypt renew` because letsencrypt is a directory. In my case I have to run `./letsencrype-auto renew` instead. I do not believe that there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall the app `letsencrypt` is obsolete, since it was renamed into `certbot` back in 2016.

https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2016/05/announcing-certbot-new-tls-robot

You should use `certbot` instead:

https://certbot.eff.org/

While were are at it:

One of the reason letsencrypt clients fail renewing certificates may also be due to the ACMEv1 protocol is reached en of life January 1st 2020, so people must switch to a client that supports ACMEv2 protocol instead:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430

Certbot does support ACMEv2 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt does no longer allow TLS-SNI-01 as a way to prove that you own the domain.

What you should do (according to this issue: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/6984) is to remove the line following line from your config file:

```
standalone_supported_challenges = "tls-sni-01,http-01"  # this guy
```

After you've removed the above line, you can start using a different authentication method like the TLS-ALPN-01 validation method. You can find a full list of validation methods here: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/ .