# How can I make SSL Lets Encrypt certificate auto renew on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssl, lets-encrypt

How can I make the certificate for [vgo site](https://www.vgopromo.com) to auto new every time so I don't have to renew it manual or it will auto renew itself?

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.vsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot
```

I have ubuntu, nginx btw and i am using letsencrypt

**Edit:**
Like Gerald Schneider suggested having certbot installed on ubuntu auto renews by default how can I check this ?

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-amd-sfo3-01:~# certbot -v
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: site.com
2: www.site.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renew Letsencrypt certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/774471/renew-letsencrypt-certificate)

Comment: Auto renew is active by default on Ubuntu if you installed certbot as a regular package.

Comment: you sure @GeraldSchneider ?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider No it is not. Otherwise I would not keep getting emails about expired website and the actual website not loading because the SSL has expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed certbot on Ubuntu as a regular package there is nothing you need to do, a systemd timer is installed automatically.

```
$ sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
$ dpkg -L certbot |grep systemd
/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service
/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run certbot twice daily

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,12:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=43200
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

When you use the `--nginx` argument to get a certificate certbot knows that nginx has to be reloaded after renewals and does so automatically.

Comment: Where is the rest of the unit file?

Comment: That is the complete unit file (for Ubuntu 22.04).

Answer (score 2):

/etc/cron.daily/certbot

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/certbot renew --renew-hook "systemctl reload nginx"
```

(or apache2 instead of nginx)

But I'd recommend to watch for certificates anyway, sometimes renewal may fail (because cron failed or someone changed Root of website or added rewrite rules or some of DNS names stopped working), I'd recommend [showcert](https://github.com/yaroslaff/showcert) for this

```
sudo showcert -q :le -w20 || echo panic
```

(send mail to yourself or do any other alert when some cert are soon to expire)

Disclaimer: showcert is my hobby project.